# Every subgroup is isomorphic to a normal subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group such that, for every subgroup $H$ of $G$, there exists a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$, such that $H$ is isomorphic to $K$. Under such conditions, can we determine the structure of $G$ ?

This question comes from the discussion of Dedekind group in group theory, which is one such that all of its subgroups are normal.  We know that a Dedekind group is an Abelian
group or a direct product of the quaternion group $Q_8$ and an Abelian group $A$, where $A$ has no elements with order $4$.

So my problem can be regarded as a promotion of Dedekind group that only requires isomorphism. I don't know how to deal with this case.

Comment: For a finite group, it implies that every Sylow subgroup is normal, and hence this is a nilpotent group, reducing the study to finite $p$-groups.

Comment: One can also consider groups where each subgroup is mapped to a normal subgroup by an automorphism. I wonder if they are different from your class.

Comment: @vrz : Automorphisms of a group $G$ send normal subgroups to normal subgroups, and non-normal subgroups to non-normal subgroups. Hence every subgroup of $G$ is mapped to a normal subgroup via some automorphism if and only if every subgroup of $G$ is  normal  (so $G$ is Dedekind).

Comment: The Heisenberg group over $\mathbb{Z}$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) is an infinite nilpotent group which is not Dedekind but satisfies your requirements. (Maybe some finite quotient satisfies them too.)

Comment: @LucGuyot Is this easy to see? Sorry but straight away I don't even see whether there are any non-cyclic non-normal subgroups.

Comment: For $2$-groups the first failures are given by $D_{16}$, $SD_{16}$ and another group of order $16$ (no 3 in the SmallGroup library). The first 2 groups contains a $C_2\times C_2$ subgroup (but no normal ones) and the second has a $C_4$-sunbgroup (but no normal ones). For order $32$ the property fails for $24$ out of $51$ groups and for order $64$ it fails for $205$ out of $267$ groups.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I don't know if it qualifies as easy or not, you will tell me. Write the discrete Heisenberg group $H$ as $\mathbb{Z}^2 \rtimes_A \mathbb{Z}$ where $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then we can show that a subgroup of $H$ is necessarily isomorphic to one of the following groups: $\{1\}, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}^2, \mathbb{Z}^2 \rtimes_{A^k} \mathbb{Z}$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and each of this group is isomorphic to a normal subgroup of $H$.

Comment: @LucGuyot : Yes indeed, there are plenty of finite homomorphic images of the Heisenberg group which satisfy the conditions of the question, but are not Dedekind. For every odd prime $p$, there is a non-Abelian group $P$ of order $p^{3}$  and exponent $p$. Every subgroup of $P$ order greater than $p$ is normal. There are non-normal subgroups of order $p$ (the centre is the only normal subgroup of order $p$, but every subgroup of order $p$ is isomorphic to the centre).

Comment: You can take a Tarski monster $G$ times $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\infty$ to get such groups. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group

Comment: Obvious examples of "generalized Dedekind" groups (if it's worth such a name) are groups of order $p^3$, $p$ prime, and, groups of order $p^4$ and exponent $p$. Among groups of order $p^4$ I guess that generalized Dedekind is more frequent than the contrary, but this has to be checked.

Answer (score 12):

Let us call $G$ a *generalised Dedekind group* if every subgroup of $G$ is isomorphic to a normal subgroup of $G$.

As expected, Dedekind groups are generalised Dedekind groups. In addition, YCor has [established](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370056/every-subgroup-is-isomorphic-to-a-normal-subgroup#comment934805_370056) that a finite generalised Dedekind group $G$ is nilpotent, since its $p$-Sylow subgroups are necessarily normal.

Note that the fundamental group of the Klein bottle, that is, $\mathbb{Z} \rtimes_{-1} \mathbb{Z} = \left\langle a, b \, \vert \, aba^{-1} = b^{-1} \right\rangle$ is an infinite generalised Dedekind group which is not nilpotent.

Here is a family of finite nilpotent groups which are generalised Dedekind groups but not Dedekind groups.

> **Claim.** Let $p$ be a prime number and let $u$ be an integer such that $u \equiv 1 \text{ mod } p \mathbb{Z}$ and $u^p \equiv 1 \text{ mod } p^2 \mathbb{Z}$. Let $$G(p, u) \Doteq \mathbb{Z}/p^2 \mathbb{Z} \rtimes_u \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$$ where the conjugation by $a \Doteq (0, 1 + p \mathbb{Z})$ induces the multiplication by $u$ on $\mathbb{Z}/p^2 \mathbb{Z}$, i.e., $aba^{-1} = b^u$ where $b \Doteq (1 + p^2 \mathbb{Z}, 0)$. Then $G(p, u)$ is a generalised Dedekind group.
> If in addition $u \not\equiv 1 \text{ mod } p^2 \mathbb{Z}$, then $G(p, u)$ is not Dedekind.

> *Proof.*
> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G(p, u)$. It is easy to check that $H$ can be generated by two elements $(x, y) = (b^k, b^la^m)$ with $k \in \{0, 1, p\}$ and $l, m \in \mathbb{Z}$.
> Let us show first that $G(p, u)$ is a generalised Dedekind group.
>
> If $k = 0$ or $m \equiv 0 \text{ mod } p\mathbb{Z}$ , then $H$ is a cyclic subgroup of order at most $p^2$ and hence isomorphic to either $\{1\}$, $\langle b \rangle$ or $\langle b^p \rangle$ which are normal in $G(p, u)$. Indeed, we have $(b^la^m)^p = 
> b^{l(1 + u^m + \dotsb + u^{m(p-1)})}$ with
> $1 + u^m + \dotsb + u^{m(p-1)} \equiv p \bmod{p\mathbb{Z}}$, hence the order of $b^la^m$ is at most $p^2$.
>
> If $k = 1$, then $H = \langle b, a^m \rangle$ which is easily seen to be normal in $G(p, u)$.
>
> Let us assume eventually that $k = p$ and $m \not\equiv 0 \text{ mod } p\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have $H = \langle b^p, b^l a^m \rangle$.
> If $(b^l a^m)^p \neq 1$, then $b^l a^m$ generates $H$ so that $H$ is isomorphic to a cyclic normal subgroup of $G(p, u)$. Otherwise $\langle b^p \rangle \cap \langle b^l a^m \rangle = \{1\}$. Since $\langle b^p \rangle$ is central in $G(p, u)$, the subgroup $H$ is isomorphic to the Abelian normal subgroup $\langle b^p, a \rangle \triangleleft G(p, u)$.
>
> Thus we have established that $G(p, u)$ is a generalised Dedekind group.
> We complete the proof by observing that $G(p, u)$ is Abelian if and only if $u \equiv 1 \text{ mod } p^2 \mathbb{Z}$.

Taking $p = 2$ and $u = 3$ yields the dihedral group of order $8$ which is the smallest finite generalised Dedekind ring which is not Dedekind.
Taking $p = 3$ and $u = 4$ provides us with an example of a $3$-group which is a generalised Dedekind but not Dedekind.

---

**Addendum.** [Geoff Robinson](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370056/every-subgroup-is-isomorphic-to-a-normal-subgroup#comment935021_370056) and [YCor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370056/every-subgroup-is-isomorphic-to-a-normal-subgroup#comment935031_370056) have observed in the comments attached to the question  that, more generally, the [groups of order $p^3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group), for $p$ a prime number, are generalised Dedekind groups. If $p \neq 2$, there are only $2$ isomorphism classes of non-Abelian groups of order $p^3$: the class of $G(p, u)$ (which does not depend on $u$) and the class of the Heisenberg group modulo $p$, that is, $H(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) \Doteq (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2 \rtimes_A \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. The proof becomes obvious once we have observed that the centers of these two groups are cyclic of order $p$ and that groups of order $p^2$ are Abelian. If $p = 2$, the latter two classes collapse in one, the isomorphism class of the [dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) of order $8$, and a new class must be considered, namely the isomorphism class of the  [quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group).

Comment: An interesting (to me at any rate) example of a $p$-group $P$ (for $p$ odd) which is not generalized  Dedekind, yet has an Abelian subgroup of index $p$ is the wreath product $\left( \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \right) \wr \left( \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \right) $. (since $P$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $p^{2}$, but no normal cyclic subgroup of order $p^{2}$).